# Best practice for onboard hardware driving

Tags: linux, drivers, hardware

When I started with computer administration (VME-bus systems), a time when drivers were necessarily built in-kernel there was some very sensible rule one should not infringe :

Never ever plug / install whatever hardware for which you don't get any appropriate driver.

The major reason for this being the high probability for the hardware to generate IRQs which, if not or inadequately handled would cause the kernel to panic.

---

It happens that, running whatever -4 or -5 linux kernel on a motherboard equipped with an Intel ICH10 southbridge, running lshw informs me of :

```
*-serial UNCLAIMED
    description: SMBus
    product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
```

And this irrespective of any setting for the CONFIG_I2C_I801 kernel option that I understand as being THE dedicated driver.

Being said that, plugged in the SMBus, I get at least a Super I/O chip (that I believe highly capable of local interrupts and for which I get a dedicated driver but of no use because of smbus being undriven) :

Is it 100% safe (I mean production grade) to leave things as they are (v.g super I/O chip undriven) or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK, the monsters have gone away now.  That's a PCI-bus device.  PCI devices are our friends.

```
$ lspci | grep SMBus
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
```

The address allocations for PCI devices are controlled by software.  The device doesn't need to listen to fixed IO ports or memory addresses.

Therefore it won't get enabled accidentally.  The standard says the device IRQ has to be specifically enabled (and there is a standard way to do so).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripheral_Component_Interconnect#Auto_configuration

There's a caveat which favours NOT loading a driver for SMBus.  The SMBus device might be controlled by ACPI firmware ([AML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acpi#Architecture)).  In that case, the kernel should not drive it.  ACPI is supposed to declare the SMBus device resources so the kernel can avoid this.  I'm not sure if it is possible for ACPI to get this wrong or not.  I think the kernel used to get it wrong, but it recognizes it now.

```
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: PCI INT B -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
ACPI: I/O resource 0000:00:1f.3 [0x400-0x41f] conflicts with ACPI region SMRG [0x400-0x40f]
ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```